# singular subject but verb changes depending on statement or question

Tags: grammatical-number, do-support

I'm married to a non-native English speaker so I often get to correct his English.  However, I can't always explain WHY one way is correct and the other is not.

I heard him ask a customer, "Where does your dad lives?"
I realized in statement form "lives" is correct.  "My dad lives here." But in question form, "lives" becomes "live" and I don't know why.

Why does "live" change to "lives" in this case: Where does your dad live? My dad lives in the city.  Both cases refer to a singular person "dad".

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Exchange! Just so you know, there is another site on this network specifically for questions about English language learning: https://ell.stackexchange.com/ There is a previous question on that site that I think is relevant to your question: [Should I say “what does it means” or “what does it mean”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27120)

Answer (score 2):

> Where **does** your dad **live**?
>
> My dad **lives** in the city.

The difference between the question and reply is that you've removed the auxiliary verb "do," which helps form the question. As [Oxford Dictionaries explains](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/auxiliary-verbs), "do" is used in verb phrases to ask questions, add emphasis, or form negative statements. Here are a few examples based on your question and answer:

> (Emphasis - present) My dad **does live** in the city.
>
> (Emphasis - past) My dad **did live** in the city, but ...
>
> (Negative) My dad **doesn't live** in the city.
>
> (Question) **Does** your dad **live** in the city?

With each example, *do* is the verb that takes number (singular and plural) and tense (like present or past). In questions, the auxiliary verb is often shifted away from the main verb, but the auxiliary verb still is the one that changes number, tense, and mood. "Live," or the verb helped by *do*, always takes a *[bare infinitive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bare-infinitive)* form, which here looks like a plural present tense verb but merely lacks any affixes like -s or -ed. In trying to modify the main verb as well as the auxiliary verb, your husband has overcorrected his speech.